# Integracion de HTML sin templateId

Tags: html, templates, integration, sendgrid

Good evening, I want to send my own html, not created in sendgrid by email, but I can't find a way to integrate it

[image]

that is my code and this is the html template that I want to send

[image]

Comment: Please don't show text in images and translate your title into English.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the contents of your `email.html` file first, then set those contents as the value of the `Content` object.

It looks like you are writing this in Java. I'd recommend you check out [this article on reading text from a file in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/) and pick your favourite method to load the contents into memory and then use them in the `Content` object.